# Appendix and cross-referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

first my code: (I added all packages I'm currently using)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{threeparttable}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Text}

Here is a chapter with text where I want to make a reference to Appendix A. Lets try the reference: Here a reference to Appendix \ref{appendix:a} and a reference to Appendix B namely Appendix \ref{appendix:b}.

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A}
\label{appendix:a}
This is the content of the appendix A. 
\chapter*{Appendix B}
\label{appendix:b}
This is the content of the appendix B.

\end{document}
```

This example has a perfectly fine reference for `Appendix A`. However, the title for `Appendix A` is done twice. Once due to `\chapter{Appendix A}` and once as the `\chapter{Appendix A}` is the first entry for the appendix. Furthermore, `\appendix` changes numerical references to alpha references.

Obviously adding the `*` for the appendix B removes the additional title, hence makes propper referencing impossible.

Anyone got an idea on how to handle this?

I already tried `\begin{appendices} ... \end{appendices}`, however, for that version the numbering of the appendix chapters were numerical and not "A, B etc "

**EDIT:** I would prefer the table of content not including the appendix chapters and within the appendices only the Chapter names. However, as mentioned before using `\chapter*{chapter_name}` makes the reference unusuable.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{threeparttable}


\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
\chapter{Text}

Here is a chapter with text where I want to make a reference to Appendix A. Lets try the reference: Here a reference to Appendix \ref{appendix:a} and a reference to Appendix B namely Appendix \ref{appendix:b}.

 \begin{appendices}
 \chapter*{Appendix A}
 \label{appendix:a}
 This is the content of the appendix A. 
 \chapter*{Appendix B}
 \label{appendix:b}
 This is the content of the appendix B.
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\appendix` command does just rename the chapter name to `Appendix`, so it's no wonder that `\Appendix A` appears twice, since you used this as the title as well. And it's `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}`

Comment: A chapter name in the appendix should be something like *additional charts*, or *material data sheets*, or *raw data* or *sourcecode of program*. Describing the content, not what it is. It would be equally silly to call your chapter `\chapter{chapter 1}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank you for correcting and replying. And yes you both are right. What I did before could not give me the wished result. Before I used `\appendix` I had used `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}`, however I was not able to create a propper looking reference as the numbering of the appendix section was numerically.

Comment: @Claude: I still don't understand what's the issue here. By default, both `\appendix` or `\begin{appendices}...` switch to alpha 'numbering' of appendix chapters or sections.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I added a new example. It shows the output for the table of contents and the look of the appendix as I would prefer it. However, the references are not working anymore due to `\chapter*{}`.

Comment: @Claude: See the possible answer, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubling `Appendix A` etc. is due to wrong usage of `\chapter{Appendix A}` -- but it can be removed (but why naming it this way, if it could be done automatically?) -- anyway, I removed the `\chaptername` header line of the the chapter title by redefinition of `\@makechapterhead`.

The removal of appendix chapters from the `ToC` can be achieved by using `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}}` after the `appendices` environment has started.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
  % Removing the entries to the toc within appendices environment with \setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}}
  % Removing the \chaptername header line in the chapter head command \@makechapterhead
  \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
      % \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      % \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
      % \par\nobreak
      % \vskip 20\p@
      % \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
\chapter{Text}

Here is a chapter with text where I want to make a reference to Appendix A. Lets try the reference: Here a reference to Appendix \ref{appendix:a} and a reference to Appendix B namely Appendix \ref{appendix:b}.




\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Appendix A}
  \label{appendix:a}
  This is the content of the appendix A. 
  \chapter{Appendix B}
  \label{appendix:b}
  This is the content of the appendix B.
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works for me! However, I agree with you that what I asked seems strange. What would be the correct usage of `\appendix` or `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}` if you only need one name for each chapter (or section) names for the appendix. In other words, if the title name _Appendix A_ and _Appendix B_ is enough as names for the appendix parts. I dont want to have _Appendix A_ with chapter name _Part A appendix A_ , _Appendix B_ with chapter name _Part A appendix B_.