# Name of appendix

Tags: appendices

using this in my thesis

```
\begin{appendix}
\chapter{}
bla bla bla...
\end{appendix}
```

is giving me heading as

[image]

But I dont want the heading as Appendix A, as I have only one appendix in my thesis. How can I name it only Appendix.

I am using document class report and I want appendix to show in ToC

Comment: Use`\chapter*`.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use. Please also tell us whether or not the appendix chapter should show up in the table of contents (assuming the document has a ToC).

Comment: `appendix` is no environment in most cases. As for the appendix name etc: See my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300121/appendix-and-cross-referencing, if you want to get rid off the `Appendix A` stuff, but still be capable of cross-referring to it